# Pop up message in Excel when a specific word is entered into a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a pop up message that will appear only when a certain word appears in a range of cells in a spreadsheet.  Currently the macro I have written displays the pop up message whenever anything is entered.  Here is the code I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G10:G40")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Exact dimensions needed for ceramic pipe due to required shop fabrication.  This can affect both pipe costs and leadtime."
    End If
End Sub
```

Again, I only want the pop up to appear when the word DURA-CORE II appears in the range of cells. I will admit right now that I know next to nothing about VBA, so I'm sure the fix is fairly simple.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, put another If inside the first. `If Target.Value = "DURA-CORE II" Then`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G10:G40")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "DURA-CORE II" Then
            MsgBox "Exact dimensions needed for ceramic pipe due to required shop fabrication.  This can affect both pipe costs and leadtime."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Range("G10:G40").Find(what:="DURA-CORE II", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Exact dimensions needed for ceramic pipe due to required shop fabrication.  This can affect both pipe costs and leadtime."
    End If
End Sub
```

in this way the user would always be informed as long as any cell in `Range("G10:G40")` has content "DURA-CORE II"

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thanks for helping out a very, very novice VBA user.

Comment: You are welcome. Then please you may want to mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you!